# Validation issue In MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation

This is my mvc validation code in model. It is working properly but just the problem is when some error in validation the form reset automatically. For example three of my fields are correct and one is empty when I click submit validation error will appear under the empty field but the field that I already provided is empty then.. How can I overcome this??

```
public class ContactModel
        {
            [Required (ErrorMessage="Name is Required")]
            [StringLength(100)]
            [Display(Order = 1)]
            public string ContactName { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Email Address is Required")]
        [RegularExpression(".+\\@.+\\..+", ErrorMessage = "Email Address is not Valid")]
        [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
        [StringLength(254)]
        [Display(Order = 2)]
        public string Email { get; set; }


        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Subject is Required")]
        [Display(Order = 3)]
        public string Subject { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Message is Required")]
        [Display(Order = 3)]
        public string Message { get; set; }

        public bool MessageSent { get; set; } 
//My View

@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true) 
   <label for="contactname">Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="ContactName" class="textfield" id="contactname" value=""  /><span class="require"> *</span>
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ContactName) 
                <label for="contactsubject">Subject</label>
                <input type="text" name="Subject" class="textfield" id="contactsubject" value=""/><span class="require"> *</span>
               @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Subject) 
                   <label for="contactemail">Your E-mail</label> 
                <input type="text" name="Email" class="textfield" id="contactemail" value="" /><span class="require"> *</span>
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email) 

                  <label for="contactmessage">Your Message</label> 
                <textarea name="Message" id="contactmessage" class="textarea" cols="8" rows="12"></textarea><span class="require"> *</span>
                  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Message) 


              <input name="Mysubmitted" id="Mysubmitted" value="Send Message" class="buttonsubmit" type="submit"/>                

}
```

Comment: Can you explain how did you write your View and how do you show error messages?

Comment: I have edited it can you see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all change all inputs and labels to `@Html.LabelFor(` and `@Html.EditorFor` and if you want to set the class use `@Html.TextBoxFor` in your view and recheck it

Comment: Thanks This seems to be working now one thing plz..  @Html.Label("Subject")
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Subject) 
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Subject)
  //How I will add the same class in the above @Html.texbox <input type="text" name="Subject" class="textfield" id="contactsubject" value=""/><span class="require"> *</span>

Comment: You can use `@Html.TextBoxFor(i => i.contactSubject, new {@class="textfield"})` , unfortunately if you want to set class or other attributes you can not use `@Html.EditorFor`

Comment: Thanks for your help it is done by your first solution.. :)                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Message ) 
I have to add css in that means to overide the css..                   @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Message, new{ @class = "NewError"} ) I added this but it is showing error..

Comment: You cant set htmlattribute for ValidationMessageFor but instead MVC will put some classes on generated validation messages that you can use that classes in your Style file via CSS